# What are the rules for (My)SQL column name resolution?

Tags: mysql, sql

If a join brings together two columns with the same name, any use of that name must be qualified with a table name or alias. As it says in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-qualifiers.html):

> You need not specify a tbl_name or db_name.tbl_name prefix for a column reference in a statement unless the reference would be ambiguous. Suppose that tables t1 and t2 each contain a column c, and you retrieve c in a SELECT statement that uses both t1 and t2. In this case, c is ambiguous because it is not unique among the tables used in the statement. You must qualify it with a table name as t1.c or t2.c to indicate which table you mean.

However, this does not seem to apply to embedded `SELECT` statements. The following is legal:

```
SELECT a, b FROM tablename WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE column1 = column2)
```

Of course, I could disambiguate the two column names to get something more useful:

```
SELECT a, b FROM tablename t1 WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2 WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column2)
```

But how are the unqualified `column1` and `column2` interpreted? What are the rules in general, and do they differ between database vendors? Is it considered good practice to disambiguate everything, or to rely on the default scope and only qualify where necessary?

Comment: probably best interpreted by table aliases, column aliases, and never doing select *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a correlated subquery, the column names are resolved by looking at the innermost scope and then moving out.  The first scope where the column is resolved is used.

Note:  You should *always* use qualified column names in correlated subqueries.  It is very easy to make a mistake like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE  t1.column1 IN (SELECT column1 FROM t2)
```

If `column1` is not in `t2`, then this is (correctly) interpreted as:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE  t1.column1 IN (SELECT t1.column1 FROM t2)
```

And this is true for all non-NULL values of `t1.column1` -- probably not the intention of the original query.

Comment: Thank you! Could you confirm whether this is a standard property of SQL, or can I expect some vendors' versions to differ?

Comment: @alexis .  .  . This is how SQL is defined.  Some databases limit the scope resolution to one nested level, however.

Comment: "And this is true for all non-NULL values of t1.column1" **provided there's at least one row in t2**